# string manipulation using split in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

```
"hello, my name is Jennifer and I live in texas, also I'm a student in.. "
```

take above string and I want to produce the following output :

```
"my name is Jennifer and I live in texas, also I'm a student in.. "
```

I can't use split like split(",") in this case because after the greeting (hello), there might be commas in the sentence. I can't use substring either because the greeting can be in halo which has vary character length.

Is it possible to split(",") but only split for the first commas?

Comment: So, you want to remove everything up to and including the first comma, right?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use `split`.  You could do this:

```
str = str.replace(/^.*?,\s*/, '');
```

What this does is return whats after the first comma.  The regular expression basically does this.  From the beginning of the line `^`, use a non-greedy expression `.*?` that searches for everything up to the first occurrence of `,` then if there happens to be any spaces afterwards `\s*`, erase that too.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = "hello, my name is Jennifer and I live in texas, also I'm a student in.. " ;

var b = a.split(",");
b.shift();
// c is what you are looking for
var c = b..join(",");
```

Comment: You might want to use `.join(",")` instead of `.toString()` or any other commas in the string will never get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

The following will return a an array spliting a string only on the first comma.

```
var temp = string.split(',')
var result = [temp.shift(), temp.join(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all but first characters including ', ':
`var trimmed = str.slice(a.indexOf(',') + 2)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
function(msg,delimiter){
  delimiter = delimiter ? delimiter : ","
  var idx = msg.indexOf(delimiter) + delimiter.length
  return msg.substring(idx)
}
```

If no delimiter is provided, it will default to ","

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.indexOf()` with parameter `" "` to match first space character, `.slice()`

```js
var str = "hello, my name is Jennifer and I live in texas, also I'm a student in.. ";
var res = str.slice(str.indexOf(" ") + 1);
console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose we have:

```
var str = "one, two, three, four"
var sep = ", "
```

Then, if we find the `.indexOf` the first instance of the substring `sep` and then get the substring of the string starting from that index plus the length of `sep` itself, we can efficiently produce the rest of the string without splitting or using regex.

```
str.substr(str.indexOf(sep) + sep.length) // -> "two, three, four"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string.split(",", 2);
```

As [String.split(String,int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) explains:

If you have more commas, Use a regex that gets "everything but the first comma". So:

```
string.split(/,(.+)?/)[1]
```

Comment: Huh? There are no `=` or `_` in the original string.